# Angular Querybuilder in a single textbox with auto suggestion of next query

Tags: angular, autocomplete, angular-material, query-builder, jql

I'm planning to build a query builder using Angular

The feature is like to have a textbox which keep autopopulating the suggestions 
**[Field + Operator + Value] + (Keyword) + ...**
Eg - *Name = 'Technosaviour' OR Age > 2*

The **autocomplete** should give suggestion of fields like [Name, Age]
Then [=, >, <, >=, etc]
Then [Techno, Saviour, Technosaviour]
Then the autocomplete should suggest [And, Or]

**Before jumping into full blown coding can anyone suggest any existing libraries available ?**
Eg - advance search (using JQL) in jira.

Similar to this  https://zebzhao.github.io/Angular-QueryBuilder/demo/ but limited to a single textbox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a POC on the project.
Made it work to some extent, feel free to use it or improve it.

**Github link**
https://github.com/luckvicky/Angular-Autocomplete-QueryBuilder/blob/master/README.md

[image: Demo]

Comment: You have used angular material here. Is it possible to use this with reactive forms?